# dubbel json output everytime switching activities

Tags: java, android, json, request, duplicates

the problem that i'm facing right now is;

on my homeactivity i have some outputs from json. but those values does change so i have to keep homeactivity updated.

when i add jsonrequest() in the onRestart()

it does get the latest values when i restart the app, or when i'm switching between activities. BUT everytime that i'm switching between activities it does add more fields. example: in my json file i do have
username: John

homeactivity shows John ; switching between activities, the homeactivity shows; John John etc..

i also have jsonrequest() in the onCreate()

```
    private void jsonrequest() {

        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject  = null;
                for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        User user = new User();
                        user.setUsername(jsonObject.getString("username"));
                        lstUser.add(user);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                setuprecyclerview(lstUser);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DashBoardActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(request) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

value in `lstUser` gets double every time because you are adding new value in `lstUser` every time, but you are not removing old value from that array.

so before adding `User` in `lstUser`, remove old value available in that array. As :

```
   public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        JSONObject jsonObject  = null;

        lstUser.clear(); // Here remove old value, so in new list you have only latest values.

        for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {
            try {
                jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                User user = new User();
                user.setUsername(jsonObject.getString("username"));
                lstUser.add(user);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        setuprecyclerview(lstUser);
    }
```

Comment: @kjmb welcome, you can accept the answer if it helps